# Macbook fans behaving wildly after SSD change

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, temperature

This is a Macbook Pro 15" Retina from 2013 (11,3). After switching my SSD for a new one, the fans started to behave wildly, spinning constantly at ~6000rpm. If I use a fan control app I can keep them in the 3000 range, which is silent, and there will be no heating whatsoever.

If I switch back to the previous SSD, fans behave normally, with low speeds on Auto and light processing load. Upon switching back to the new one, again I get high speed fans.

I've tried: PRAM reset, SMC reset, OS reinstall from scratch.

What could explain this behavior?

Comment: What SSD did you change it out to?  The 2013 MBPs no longer use 2.5" SATA SSDs.

Comment: It's the other kind. Looks like an m.2 pcie chip.

Comment: There are compatibility issues with that type of SSD - it's important you know the brand/model of the SSD to see if it's fully compatible.

Comment: I switched mine for an SSD removed from a Macbook Air.

It works 100% except for the weird fan issue.

Comment: Pulling.....teeth....argh.....  Model year of the MacBook Air?   Please remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: I really can't tell. Bought it over ebay. It's supposed to be compatible, as it's the exact same pinout. It's been working flawlessly for over 3 months, albeit the fan issue is still there.

Comment: @lotcarneiro, try this Apple Support page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201862 - should help you identify your MacBook Air.

Comment: I got a Macbook Pro. The new SSD came from a Macbook Air (possibly) according to the ebay ad.

Comment: Sounds like the newly-installed SSD wasn't a direct replacement. But without knowing which Macbook Pro, and which Macbook Air -- there were many of both models -- it's impossible for any of us to say.

Comment: I think it's obvious that the SSD is the issue. Either it's broken or not compatible, just because the connector fits does not mean it's 100% compatible. In this case, there is probably some issue with thermal sensors (maybe visible in tools like iStat).

Comment: It's indeed obvious that the SSD is somehow to blame. What actually puzzles me, and motivates me to pose the question, is **how** exactly does it interfere with the fans/temperature monitoring functions and nothing else. What in this computer's architecture makes a disk change result in fans running wild? I'm a heavy user of this machine, and with the fan app keeping speeds under control, everything is working 100%.